# Why is the continuous dual of $\ell_1$ (i.e. $\ell_\infty$) not separable while $\ell_1$ itself is separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

So I do know how to prove $\ell_1^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$. In finite dimensional vector space $V$, one has $V^*\cong V$. However, $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ are two very difference spaces (one is separable and the other is not). So it seems there is something else going on in this infinite dimensional case. Can someone give some explanation why it happens?

I asked my funtional analysis prof, and he said the underlying argument is related to measure theory and did not go into the details. I am now taking a measure theory course and has some knowledge with infinite product of measurable spaces, so this question came up to my mind again.

Comment: As supinf says, it's really more suprising that $V^* \simeq V$ for finite dimensional spaces than that $V^* \not\simeq V$ for infinite dimensional spaces. One would not really expect an iso there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Hilbert space $V$ one has $V^*\cong V$ due to Riesz' representation theorem.
Since all finite dimensional vector spaces are linearly isomorphic to a Hilbert space,
we also have $V^*\cong V$.

However, for an arbitrary Banach space $V$ there is (a-priori) no particular reason why $V^* \cong V$.
Thus it should not be surprising that $V$ is different from $V^*$ for some spaces.
For example, $\ell_p \not\cong \ell_p^*$ if $p\in (1,\infty)\setminus\{2\}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Riesz' representation theorem!